# Choosing a Job based on languages?

Tags: programming-languages

How often is language the deciding factor for selecting a job?

Many of us here are well versed in many languages, C++, Java, C#, and likely have many other languages under our belt for the right occassion (really any occasion is the right occasion for Python, AMIRITE?), so this isn't so much a question of choosing a job that is a good fit based on your skill set. Rather, if you are skilled with most languages, do you pick your favorite, or do you follow the money (given the tight economy).

I'm considering coming out of retirement, and have started to look around and what's available.

Over the years, I've moved towards C# and Python; many jobs in the area are looking for .NET developers, but there are plenty of them that do not. I cut my teef on C++, consider myself adept at the language, and know my way around a Java. But I find myself really digging what they're doing to C#, and I have always loved python.

Even if the work will be interesting, how important is the language to you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that although in its essence programming is bigger than any language(languages are just the means, not the goals) everyone has a preference toward some languages. However, it often turns out that our preferences are towards languages not considered mainstream.

I live and work in Bulgaria(a country known from the movies as the center of crime in Europe, though that's not the case). Here 90% of the job ads are for PHP, Java and C# developers... There is also C for embedded development(which I hate), C++ (for maintenance of older systems - no one starts new projects in C++ anymore) and Cobol :-) I'd very much like to make money developing in Clojure or Ruby for instance, but the reality is that there is simply no demand around here. Of the three options I've found Java to appeal most to me - it's a nice language, with a nice community around it and a great VM behind it. So I naturally consider Java ads first, but I'm always open to any challenges as long as find them intriguing...

Answer (score 3):

I would think that one would have a bias towards not just the language they want to develop in, but in the environment and type of applications they are likely to be working with. I think that would be the deciding factor?

Answer (score 2):

Java - Coffee grinder

Python - Snake charmer

C - Optician

C# - Laser eye surgeon

C++ - Night vision goggle manufacturer

Ruby - Jeweller

.NET - Fisherman

Answer (score 2):

the language itself doesnot matter so much, as the technology used does.

for example, a php/mySQL developer could easier convert to ASP.NET/MSSQL, than a .NET Windows Forms programmer will. I was both and felt more support from my php/mysql skills than my desktop C# programming ones.

But when the working process is annoying to you (e.g. you don't even want to go back to C++ coz it was hell for you), you better go find .NET desktop jobs - you will find that 90% of work done in the past by you in C++ was abstracted in .NET libraries and you'll get more fun from programming (though some people love that so-called 'c++ hell' for hacking).

as Chuck Jazdzewski fatherly said, (at the end of http://www.removingalldoubt.com/PermaLink.aspx/a32977e2-cb7d-42ea-9d25-5e539423affd ) , programming is fun, but shipping is your job. Joel Spolsky (www.joelonsoftware.com) has also nice entries about that.

Consider this when you are looking for a new working environment.

Answer (score 1):

For a coder, who's profession is based on it, is should be the main deciding factor. (...with Money a very close second!)

Comment: If you fix "programmer" with "coder", that would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've chosen Java. I know many more, but I think its the best decision to stick with one. If you work one year Java, one year c#, one year python you will not get a job as Java programmer that should have at least 3 years of experience.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound shallow but I tend to stick with the one I know best. Having spent several years in C# and .NET I wouldn't go back to PHP or Java, not because they are bad but rather I don't want to have to re-learn everything again... it would be sort of like starting all over again.